# Static Method won't return the proper value

Tags: java, oop, static-methods

Suppose I have two classes: **public First{}** and **public Second{}**. In the **First** class there was only *main()* method and the **Second** has few instances.
The point is, I have to call the **Second** class' static method from within the **First**, and that static method should return a value of the overall price of all instances of the **Second**

Here's what I tried:

```java
public class Second {

    private static int totalCost = 0;
    private int totalPrice = 0;
    
    public static void increaseTotalCost(int totalPrice) {
        Second.totalCost += totalPrice;
    }
    
    public void add(String name, int price, int count) {
        totalPrice += count * price;
        increaseTotalCost(totalPrice); 
    }

    public static int getTotalCost() {
        return Second.totalCost;
    }
    public int getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }
}
```

```java
public class First {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

          Second test1 = new Second();
          test1.add("someName", 200, 1);
          test1.add("randomName", 140, 1);

          Second test2 = new Second();
          test2.add("anotherName", 9670, 3);

          System.out.println("The overall price is: " + 
          Second.getTotalCost());
  }
}
```

While I'm not getting any errors, I still see the invalid output. So, the questions are: has it something to do with the *add()* method or *increaseTotalCost()*, or *getTotalCost()*?

And here's the actual output:

```java
    public class First {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Second test1 = new Second();
            test1.add("anyName", 1, 1);
            test1.add("randomName", 2, 1);

            Second test2 = new Second();
            test2.add("xxx", 3, 1);
            test2.add("yyy", 5, 1);
            test2.add("zzz", 1, 1);
    
            System.out.println("test1 : " + "\nTotal Price: " + 
                test1.getTotalPrice()); // outputs 3
            System.out.println("test2 : " + "\nTotal Price: " + 
                test1.getTotalPrice()); // outputs 9

            System.out.println("Total cost of all instances: " + 
                Second.getTotalCost()); // outputs 24
    }
}
```

Comment: `static` members are shared among all instances of the class.  It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, show the input data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Do not mix static and non-static methods unless you have a good reason.   Methods that are called off on an instance hang off of the instance of the method.  Each Instance has its own stack trace.  For static, all static methods hang off the class directly.  I think you'll do better to have the static method converted to hang off of an instance and then call your method.

Comment: what value do you see?

Comment: Thank you for your time gentlemen! @JimGarrison It's just that I need to calculate the overall price of all instances using public static method(), public static getter(), and private static field -- these are conditions. The way I see it, it kind of makes sense to make totalCost static because it's clearly stands for the total price of each and every instance together, am I not right? Otherwise, I would have to call the calculation each time an instance of Second{} is created, while also making it "unprotected" and volatile, right?

Comment: @rascio: Sorry, I'm just stupefied. I've just updated my original post, hope that'll be sufficient

Comment: Your life and code is going to be easier if you separate the concerns of *being* a `Second` from *managing a list* of `Second` object. I suggest creating a `Stock` class (or whatever you want to call it) and every time you create a `Second` to `add()` it to the Stock instance, which will avoid using `static` anything (which is a good thing).

Comment: @Bohemian, Thing is, that I'm under specific constraints: I cannot create any class besides these two, and I have to use static methods and static fields. Which is, to be honest, at this point (and in this particular case) I can't consider as a bad thing. But then again, I'm total newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through this:

```
public void add(String name, int price, int count) {
    totalPrice += count * price;
    increaseTotalCost(totalPrice); 
}
```

We do

```
    test1.add("anyName", 1, 1);
```

OK, so totalPrice was 0, and becomes 0 + 1 * 1 = 1.
totalCost was 0, and becomes 0 + 1 = 1.

Now

```
    test1.add("randomName", 2, 1);
```

So totalPrice was 1, and becomes 1 + 2 * 1 = 3.
totalCost was 1 and becomes 1 + 3 = 4.

You've gone wrong already.

What is lacking is any definition of what you **mean** by the words "total cost" and "total price".  Total price seems to be the accumulated cost of all 'added' entries on a single instance of the class, so that looks ok.  But then repeatedly adding the entire increasing total price to total cost is meaningless.

You probably intended to increase the total cost by the same amount that the total price was increased by, since that makes sense. So you want to add the same individual transaction sum (count * price) to each of totalPrice and totalCost.

Thus:

```
public void add(String name, int price, int count) {
    int thisSale = count * price;
    totalPrice += thisSale;
    increaseTotalCost(thisSale);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. Sorry, but for now, I don't understand how's the last part of your answer is going to help. Would you be so kind to elaborate on that? Here's the pseudo-form of what I am to achieve: total cost(x, y) = (first instance(x) + total price(x)) + (second instance(y) + total price(y)).

Comment: If your pseudo-form is correct then your original result is correct. But I see no sense in that computation.  What I suppose you want is: total_cost(x,y) = total_price(x) + total_price(y), where each of the total_price() values is the sum of the individual transactions on that instance, and of course total_cost gets updated each time one of the total_price values changes.  I added a little to my answer.

Comment: Yes, now I see, now I get it! Bless you, dear sir!